# Access points of geometric path data in PostgreSQL 8.1

Tags: postgresql, spatial, postgis, postgresql-8.1

Summary:

I would like to perform basic operations on the points of geometric path data contained in a PostgreSQL 8.1 server which I do not have administrative access to. In particular I would like to be able to iterate over these points using SQL and to access paths as arrays (or something functionally equivalent).

---

Background:

I'm a novice database user who is working with an unsupported legacy application which is using PostgreSQL 8.1 as a back-end database. I would like to be able to manually run some sanity checks on the data in the database in pure SQL (or PL/pgSQL), i.e. I'd like to be able to avoid using an external programming language, which is what I'm currently doing.

Several tables in the database include columns containing geometric data. Here is a description of one such table:

```
psql -U "${appuser}" -d "${appdatabase}" -c '\d+ path_table'

            Table "public.path_table"
 Column |  Type   | Modifiers | Description 
--------+---------+-----------+-------------
 id     | integer | not null  | 
 path   | path    | not null  | 
Indexes:
    "path_table_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Check constraints:
    "path_table_id_check" CHECK (id > 0)
Has OIDs: no
```

I consulted the section on [Geometric Functions and Operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-geometry.html) from the [PostgreSQL 8.1 Manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/), but to no avail.

Since this might be relevant, I'll mention that I believe that PostGIS 1.3.6 is installed, i.e.:

```
$ psql -U "${appuser}" -d "${appdatabase}" -c 'SELECT PostGIS_full_version();'

                                  postgis_full_version                                  
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 POSTGIS="1.3.6" GEOS="3.1.1-CAPI-1.6.0" PROJ="Rel. 4.7.1, 23 September 2009" USE_STATS
(1 row)
```

My understanding is that I can get a list of all installed functions by using the psql `\df` meta-command, i.e.

```
$ psql -U "${appuser}" -d "${appdatabase}" -c '\df'
```

My understanding is also that all of the available PostGIS commands should be prefixed by the string 'ST_' (denoting spatial type), so that the following should produce a list of all the available PostGIS commands:

```
$ psql -U "${appuser}" -d "${appdatabase}" -Alt -c '\df' | cut -d'|' -f2 | grep -i '^st_'
```

Inspecting this list didn't produce any likely candidates besides the ST_Dump function, which doesn't appear to apply to a path type:

```
SELECT st_dump(path_column) FROM table;

ERROR:  function st_dump(path) does not exist
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts.
```

Apparently the st_dump argument needs to be of type geometry, so I tried following the hint and casting the path to a geometry type:

```
SELECT st_dump(path_column::geometry) FROM table;

ERROR:  cannot cast type path to geometry
```

I also consulted the [Geometry Accessors](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.3/ch06.html#id438545) of the [PostGIS 1.3.6 Manual](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.3) but apparently I don't know enough to be able to cull a solution from the documentation.

Comment: Can you show us the full definition of your table, please? And to fully understand, you want the WKT (Well-known text) of the data, for verification purposes?

Comment: 8.1? Seriously? That's prehistoric. Anyway, maybe PostGIS was installed in a different schema that isn't on the `search_path`? Try `\df *.ST*`? (Assuming that works in 8.1)

Comment: Also, `path` is a [built-in PostgreSQL data type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-geometric.html#AEN6589), at least in current versions. Not a PostGIS type. I think PostGIS provides functions to convert `path` to `geometry` and otherwise work with it; maybe a look at the manual for your version will be informative.

Comment: @Kassandry Thank you for your response. I added a table description per your request; please let me know if that's not what you were looking for. I'm not sure how to get the WKT – the st_astext function is producing an error.

Comment: @CraigRinger Unfortunately I'm completely serious. Your suggested command works, but I'm not sure what the purpose is – are you suggesting that another version of PostGIS might be installed somewhere? I apologize if my wording seemed to suggest that the path datatype was not a native type; I only mentioned PostGIS because I thought it might be relevant to the situation. Thank you for your help.

Comment: If it's a "native" `path` type, as opposed to a PostGIS `path` type, you should just be able to simply do `SELECT id, path FROM path_table ORDER BY id;` and work with them from there without needing to do anything with PostGIS functions.

Comment: @Kassandry I see that I can use a query such as the one you described in order to get the paths themselves, but I don't know how to access the elements of those paths with SQL.

Comment: With PostGIS 2.1+ it's possible to cast a `path` to `geometry`.  See http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/220934/18189.

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Create a temporary table to store the extracted points
CREATE TEMP TABLE extracted_points (id INTEGER, point TEXT);

-- Loop through each row in the path_table
DO $$ 
DECLARE
  path_row RECORD;
BEGIN
  FOR path_row IN (SELECT id, path FROM path_table) LOOP
    -- Convert the path to a text representation
    EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO extracted_points (id, point) VALUES ($1, $2)' USING path_row.id, ST_AsText(path_row.path);
  END LOOP;
END $$;

-- Now, the extracted_points table contains the path id and its points as text
SELECT * FROM extracted_points;
```

Please note that the above code is not very efficient since it loops through each row of path_table. In newer versions of PostgreSQL and PostGIS, there are better ways to handle this, but with PostgreSQL 8.1 and PostGIS 1.3.6, this is a workaround to achieve your goal of extracting points using SQL only.